# Can I use Google map tiles with osmdroid?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am developing an app which support Google Map tiles  osmdroid. It is possible to use Google map tiles with osmdroid?

Comment: Technically?  Probably so.  Legally?  Probably not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, there are restrictions in Terms of Service.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

Have a look at paragraph 10.4 d,e.

> No use of Content without a Google map. Unless the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation without a corresponding Google map. For example, you may display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits this use.
>
> No use of Content with a non-Google map. You must not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation that contains a non-Google map